# Regex to Match Pattern 5ABXYXYXY

Tags: python, regex

I am working on mobile number of 9 digits.

I want to use regex to match numbers with pattern `5ABXYXYXY`.
A sample I have is `529434343`

*What I have tried*

I have the below pattern to match it.

```
r"^\d*(\d)(\d)(?:\1\2){2}\d*$"
```

However, this pattern matches another pattern I have which is `5XXXXXXAB`
a sample for that is `555555532`.

**What I want** I want to edit my regex to match the first pattern only `5ABXYXYXY` and ignore this one `5XXXXXXAB`

Comment: Is `543434343` a valid match considering `43` repeats 4 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^\d*((\d)(?!\2)\d)\1{2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9vGThI/3).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `((\d)(?!\2)\d)` - Group 1: a digit (captured into Group 2), then another digit (not the same as the preceding one)
- `\1{2}` - two occurrences of Group 1 value
- `$` -  end of string.

Answer (score 1):

To match `5ABXYXYXY` where `AB` should not be same as `XY` matching 3 times, you may use this regex:

```bash
^\d*(\d{2})(?!\1)((\d)(?!\3)\d)\2{2}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DrdIhI/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `\d*`: Match 0 or more digits
- `(\d{2})`: Match 2 digits and capture in group #1
- `(?!\1)`: Make sure we don't have same 2 digits at next position
- `(`: Start capture group #2

  - `(\d)`: Match and capture a digit in capture group #3
  - `(?!\3)`: Make sure we don't have same digit at next position as in 3rd capture group
  - `\d`: Match a digit
- )`: End capture group #2
- `\2{2}`: Match 2 pairs of same value as in capture group #2
- `$`: End